# Use paho-mqtt with PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, mqtt

How I can use callback function from QThread?

Callback function on_message does not print any data.
In run() I connect to mqtt-broker and subscribe on topic. on_message must work when I get new message.

Example simple QT app. Change value event connected with simple QLCD. Subscription topic took from [dashboard](http://www.mqtt-dashboard.com/)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLCDNumber, QSlider,
                             QVBoxLayout, QApplication)
from random import uniform, normalvariate, randint
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.data=DataThread()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(lcd)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.data.valueChanged.connect(lcd.display)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Callback')
        self.data.start()
        self.show()

class DataThread(QThread):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(object)
    val=0

    def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
        mstr=msg.payload.decode("ascii")
        val=mstr
        self.valueChanged.emit(val)

    def on_subscribe(mqttc, obj, mid, granted_qos):
        print("Subscribed: "+str(mid)+" "+str(granted_qos))

    def run(self):
        msg = subscribe.simple("shok2", hostname="broker.hivemq.com")
        print("%s %s" % (msg.topic, msg.payload))
        mqttc = mqtt.Client()
        mqttc.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
        mqttc.on_message = self.on_message
        mqttc.connect("broker.hivemq.com")
        print("subsrcibe")
        mqttc.subscribe("shok2")
        mqttc.loop_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Added example with mqtt subscription

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not necessary to use threads, just follow the logic of Qt: let's use signals. In the following code I show an advance of the library of an MQTT client that I am implementing that at least up to now implements what you want, in next days I will add more functionalities.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


class MqttClient(QtCore.QObject):
    Disconnected = 0
    Connecting = 1
    Connected = 2

    MQTT_3_1 = mqtt.MQTTv31
    MQTT_3_1_1 = mqtt.MQTTv311

    connected = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    disconnected = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    stateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    hostnameChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    portChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    keepAliveChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    cleanSessionChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    protocolVersionChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    messageSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MqttClient, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_hostname = ""
        self.m_port = 1883
        self.m_keepAlive = 60
        self.m_cleanSession = True
        self.m_protocolVersion = MqttClient.MQTT_3_1

        self.m_state = MqttClient.Disconnected

        self.m_client =  mqtt.Client(clean_session=self.m_cleanSession,
            protocol=self.protocolVersion)

        self.m_client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.m_client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.m_client.on_disconnect = self.on_disconnect


    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, notify=stateChanged)
    def state(self):
        return self.m_state

    @state.setter
    def state(self, state):
        if self.m_state == state: return
        self.m_state = state
        self.stateChanged.emit(state) 

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(str, notify=hostnameChanged)
    def hostname(self):
        return self.m_hostname

    @hostname.setter
    def hostname(self, hostname):
        if self.m_hostname == hostname: return
        self.m_hostname = hostname
        self.hostnameChanged.emit(hostname)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, notify=portChanged)
    def port(self):
        return self.m_port

    @port.setter
    def port(self, port):
        if self.m_port == port: return
        self.m_port = port
        self.portChanged.emit(port)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, notify=keepAliveChanged)
    def keepAlive(self):
        return self.m_keepAlive

    @keepAlive.setter
    def keepAlive(self, keepAlive):
        if self.m_keepAlive == keepAlive: return
        self.m_keepAlive = keepAlive
        self.keepAliveChanged.emit(keepAlive)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool, notify=cleanSessionChanged)
    def cleanSession(self):
        return self.m_cleanSession

    @cleanSession.setter
    def cleanSession(self, cleanSession):
        if self.m_cleanSession == cleanSession: return
        self.m_cleanSession = cleanSession
        self.cleanSessionChanged.emit(cleanSession)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, notify=protocolVersionChanged)
    def protocolVersion(self):
        return self.m_protocolVersion

    @protocolVersion.setter
    def protocolVersion(self, protocolVersion):
        if self.m_protocolVersion == protocolVersion: return
        if protocolVersion in (MqttClient.MQTT_3_1, MQTT_3_1_1):
            self.m_protocolVersion = protocolVersion
            self.protocolVersionChanged.emit(protocolVersion)

    #################################################################
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def connectToHost(self):
        if self.m_hostname:
            self.m_client.connect(self.m_hostname, 
                port=self.port, 
                keepalive=self.keepAlive)

            self.state = MqttClient.Connecting
            self.m_client.loop_start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def disconnectFromHost(self):
        self.m_client.disconnect()

    def subscribe(self, path):
        if self.state == MqttClient.Connected:
            self.m_client.subscribe(path)

    #################################################################
    # callbacks
    def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
        mstr = msg.payload.decode("ascii")
        # print("on_message", mstr, obj, mqttc)
        self.messageSignal.emit(mstr)

    def on_connect(self, *args):
        # print("on_connect", args)
        self.state = MqttClient.Connected
        self.connected.emit()

    def on_disconnect(self, *args):
        # print("on_disconnect", args)
        self.state = MqttClient.Disconnected
        self.disconnected.emit()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.lcd_number = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber()
        lay.addWidget(self.lcd_number)

        self.client = MqttClient(self)
        self.client.stateChanged.connect(self.on_stateChanged)
        self.client.messageSignal.connect(self.on_messageSignal)

        self.client.hostname = "broker.hivemq.com"
        self.client.connectToHost()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_stateChanged(self, state):
        if state == MqttClient.Connected:
            print(state)
            self.client.subscribe("shok2")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_messageSignal(self, msg):
        try:
            val = float(msg)
            self.lcd_number.display(val)
        except ValueError:
            print("error: Not is number")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Based on this answer I have created a library to use paho with PyQt5 and PySide2: https://github.com/eyllanesc/qtmqtt

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to create the method on_connect use the subscribe on on_connect method not on run.

```
def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print "Connected", rc
    client.subscribe("shok2")

def run(self):
    msg = subscribe.simple("shok2", hostname="broker.hivemq.com")
    print("%s %s" % (msg.topic, msg.payload))
    mqttc = mqtt.Client()
    mqttc.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
    mqttc.on_message = self.on_message
    mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
    mqttc.connect("broker.hivemq.com")
    mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Do not use loop_forever() as it blocks the event loop of Qt, instead use loop_start()